# Facebook Unity3D

Tags: facebook, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to integrate my Unity game with facebook and I've got some problem. I've wrote something like that:

```
void Awake()
{
    FB.Init(onInitComplet, onHideUnit);
    Debug.Log("Initialized!");
}

private void onInitComplet()
{
    Debug.Log("FB initialized");
}

private void onHideUnit(bool isGameShown)
{
    if (!isGameShown)
    {
        Time.timeScale = 0;
    }
    else
    {
        Time.timeScale = 1;
    }
}
```

And when I'm starting game, I get error:

```
NullReferenceException: Facebook object is not yet loaded.  Did you call FB.Init()?
FB.get_FacebookImpl () (at Assets/Facebook/Scripts/FB.cs:31)
FB.Init (Facebook.InitDelegate onInitComplete, System.String appId, Boolean cookie, Boolean logging, Boolean status, Boolean xfbml, Boolean frictionlessRequests, Facebook.HideUnityDelegate onHideUnity, System.String authResponse) (at Assets/Facebook/Scripts/FB.cs:160)
FB.Init (Facebook.InitDelegate onInitComplete, Facebook.HideUnityDelegate onHideUnity, System.String authResponse) (at Assets/Facebook/Scripts/FB.cs:92)
FBHolder.Awake () (at Assets/Scripts/Facebook/FBHolder.cs:25)
```

What can be wrong?

Answer (score 0):

As a rule of thumb, all initialisation that is referencing other components and game objects should be implemented in Start method instead of Awake, because you can't be sure that Awake method was called on other objects or that they have even been properly created by Unity yet. I don't know about FB issue in particular, but I think that moving this code from Awake to Start should solve this issue.